# Прокрутка модального окна Bootstrap в самый низ

Tags: bootstrap

Никак не могу найти ответ. 
Есть диалоговое окно Bootstrap, высота которого больше высоты экрана. Колесиком или полосой прокрутки я его могу скроллить. Но как это сделать программно на jquery? 
Допустим, открылось диалоговое окно с большой высотой и в нем кнопка, при нажатии на которую окно автоматом прокрутится вниз.
Добавлять скролл в само диалоговое окно не хочется...

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена:

```
$('#modal').animate({ scrollTop: $('#modal .modal-dialog').height() }, 500);
```

Этот код опустит диалоговое окно в самый низ.